# How to display system info except login Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, login, virtual-terminal

When login in `Ubuntu` terminal, I can see the following system info:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-25-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Fri May 13 13:00:37 EDT 2016

  System load:  0.16               Processes:           173
  Usage of /:   11.8% of 18.32GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 10%                IP address for eth0: 192.168.80.130
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/
```

Is there any method to display this info when I use this machine except first login?

Comment: Do you want that exact message or do you only need the "System information" section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "the message if the day". It is generated by running a collection of scripts in the directory: `/etc/update-motd.d`.
You can re-run these scripts by typing this command in a terminal.

```
sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/
```

Helpfully, this will inform you if any packages have updates available or if your system needs a re-start.